# AJAX script not working in Firefox

Tags: ajax, firefox

I have written an AJAX script to read information from a database and inject it into a .php file as HTML. It works in IE8, Safari, Chrome but not Firefox. No errors displayed or anything, it just doesn't execute at all.

Here's the code:

```
function queryDatabase(query)
{
    alert();
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
        alert();
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
    else
        {
        alert();
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4)
            {
            content.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        else
            {
            content.innerHTML = "<center><span style=\"color: #ff7e00; font-size: 30px;\">LOADING...</div></center>";
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET",query,true);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

(The alerts were for testing purposes but none of them show up in Firefox)

Here's the divs it's used on:

```
<div onClick="queryDatabase('latestquery.php')" style="cursor: pointer;">TEST</div> <div onClick="queryDatabase('testtagquery.php')" style="cursor: pointer;">TEST</div>
```

Any help is appreciated :)
Thanks
Sam

Comment: Just a helpful comment: I'd recommend to take a look for jQuery (http://jquery.com). It will save you from all browser specific pains and more.

Comment: If you put an alert inside the 'if(xmlhttp.readyState==4){}' condition, do you see it? If you do it may be a problem with the display of the result, not the fetching of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for a start you can't do `alert()` in Firefox - the argument isn't optional.  Change it to `alert(0)` and see what happens the.

Secondly, I don't see where you set `content` - is that a global variable you've got initialised somewhere?

You can check for script errors in Firefox by bringing up the Error Console (Tools -> Error Console or Ctrl + Shift + J).
To help even more, install [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843).

Edit: if `content` is just the id of an element you need to do `document.getElementById(content).innerHTML = ...;`

Comment: content is the id of a div in the HTML file. The div is empty. Thanks for the info about alert(); in Firefox, the script does appear to run but it's still not having the desired result :/

As I said, it works perfectly in other browsers.

Comment: +1 - Using firebug to display the error is the only real solution here, on Firefox.

Comment: I just tried this in firebug and removing all the alerts fixes it.  Remove the alerts.

Comment: Even without the alerts, as shown above the state change function never gets called.

Comment: "Edit: if content is just the id of an element you need to do document.getElementById(content).innerHTML = ...;"

That worked :D Thank you very much :)

Comment: Cool, if that fixed it for you, you can accept the answer by clicking on the big tick.  Welcome to Stack Overflow btw :)

Answer (score 1):

The best advice I can give you is to start using a javascript framework that implements the AJAX functionality for you and makes it much easier to write code using it.

Using jQuery this would look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
     $('#div1').click( function() {
         queryDb(this,'lastestquery.php');
     });

     $('#div2').click( function() {
         queryDb(this,'testtagquery.php');
     });
 });

 function queryDB(div,url) {
    $(div).load( url );
 }
</script>

<div id="div1" style="cursor: pointer;">TEST</div>
<div id="div2" style="cursor: pointer;">TEST</div>
```

Note that I would probably also use a CSS class to assign the cursor as well.

```
<div id="div1" class="clickable">TEST</div>
```

Loaded via a CSS file

```
.clickable {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Tried that and it doesn't seem to have the desired result... I assume that this just gets data from the database and doesn't actually display it?

Comment: jQuery is great but it will help you if you know what's going on behind the scenes

Comment: @Samwhoo -- it assumes that your php code returns HTML and replaces the contents of the DIV with it.  What about it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: It doesn't work because you are missing a >  after your first line!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: This worked on the face of it, but it looks now like it was not the actual solution.

Taking your code above and moving the xmlhttp.open call to before you set the state change function worked for me. Like this:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET",query,true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
 if(xmlhttp.readyState==4)
 {
   content.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
 else
 {
   content.innerHTML = "..";
 }
}
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the lastquery.php file if this helps:

```
<?php
            $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","***");
            mysql_select_db("main", $con);

            //GET MOST RECENT POST ID
            $last_id_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles");
            $last_id_result = mysql_fetch_array($last_id_query);
            $last_id = (int)$last_id_result['id'] - 2;

            //USE MOST RECENT POST ID TO GENERATE LAST 5 ARTICLES SUBMITTED
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id > '$last_id' ORDER BY id DESC");

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
              {
              echo "<div id=\"centralcontent\"><div class=\"articleheading\"><strong>".$row['title']."</strong></div><div class=\"tag\">&nbsp; &nbsp; in ".$row['tag']."</div><div class=\"articleinfo\">".$row['date']."</div>";
              echo "<div class=\"articlecontent\">".$row['content']."</div></div>";
              }

            mysql_close($con);
            ?>
```